# Async functino with check loop inside

Tags: c#, android, http, asynchronous, xamarin

I am trying to create a task which runs async to the ui of my android app. In the current code I try to make a http request to a PHP-server and then display the resault on the app.

```
async Task checkOnDb()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"event", "update" },
            {"session_id", session_id },
        };
        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        string responseString = "";
        while (update)
        {
            response = await client.PostAsync(connection, content);
            responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            setState(responseString);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I call the Task like this in an other async function

```
await checkOnDb();
```

When I call the function which calls the checkOnDb-Task my app crashes.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace which indicates why your app crashes? If so, please edit your question and add it

Comment: No sry, but i will take a look at it.

Comment: What is setState doing? Also you're not writing java, methods should start with a CapitalLetter

Comment: setState just puts the string from the request into a textView on the UI

Comment: Without a stacktrace we can't really help, it can be everything. Are you sure your "response.Content" is unequal null? So you make sure your request is valid and retrieves a valid response from the server?

Comment: I tryed to call the checkOnDb() in a non async function and now it works, but still dont know why it crashed

Comment: from an async context (out of another thread, not the main UI thread ) you cant directly set text in your textView. You have to invoke itwith a delegate function.

Comment: Ok i noticed that before

Comment: But can u run an async from inside another async function?

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, please create an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false);` should resolve your Context issue.